# Dynamic 2 html button "Submit" control, how to know which button is click in code

Tags: asp.net

I am implementing dynamic button as html control, but the button's click event is not fired.

my code is

```
for (iDynamicPageCount = 0; iDynamicPageCount < GrdResult.PageCount - 1; iDynamicPageCount++)
{
    string sDynamicSybntext = 
        "<li><button type=\"submit\" runat=\"server\" onserverclick=\"btnNext1_Click\" id=" + strName + ">" + (iDynamicPageCount + 2).ToString() + "</button></li>";
    sbPaging.Append(sDynamicSybntext);
}
```

`GrdResult.PageCount - 1` number of button will create.

at last add into literal control

```
p0.Text = sbPaging.ToString();
```

when i click the button `btnNext1_Click` event is not firing, only postback occurs.

Comment: I think you need to add this button control to page controls collection like `page.controls.add(btnNext)`. have a trail.

Answer (score 0):

Your all buttons are not server side because you are just appending string in response stream. so please remove `runat` and `onserverclick`.

like (generate your buttons through loop I added for example)

```
<input type="submit" name="pageButton" value="value1" />
<input type="submit" name="pageButton" value="value2" />
<input type="submit" name="pageButton" value="value3" />
<input type="submit" name="pageButton" value="value4" />
```

and you can get clicked button's value on page load event from request object

```
 string ValueOfClickedButton = Request["pageButton"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see the issue that you are using type="submit"

So please change it to type="button"

```
type="submit" will submit the form by default
type="button" will not submit form and have no default behaviour.
```

Comment: If he does this then the page will not submit at all and it definitely will not hit the serverside function he wants it to hit.